# Eyeglasses Detection in facial image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on detection of eyeglasses in frontal image. My goal is to just detect presence of eyeglasses without localizing exact position.

Work given in the paper at http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs100440050002 does exactly the same thing.

In this work area below eyes and between eyes is used for edge detection. Six measures are computed, M1 to M6. I am not able to get following things from the paper.

1. Once the six measures are computed how is the detection performed?
2. Is it necessary to specify parameters `p,q,r,s` (please see figure 1 in the paper) accurately? The database I am working on has images taken from unequal distance.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The paper is behind a paywall and I would have skipped it, but I think the problem is interesting.

1. I have only skimmed it, but it looks like they use histograms of the six measurements to show that all six results in a bimodal distribution, where no-glasses/glasses are well separated. The find that combining M2 and M5 gives the best result.
2. As I read it, the parameters are fixed and you should optimise them. So you should probably apply some preprocessing so you get images that are more equal. They test on a data set where this has been done and find that it decreases performance, but combining measurements can improve it.

Anyways, I think you should consider researching some more before committing to this method. A quick search for "automatic eyeglass detection" gives several promising hits.

Comment: :Thanks your explanation helped me.This method works fine for detection purpose.